# Wordpress install checking permissions of user id 0

Tags: users, user-roles, permissions, user-access

I'm getting the popular `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.` But I can't seem to find a solution for the cause of it on my blog setup. I've added the function

```
function check_user_perms( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
    print($args[1]);
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'check_user_perms', 0, 3 );
```

Which seems to print the user id on all normal pages, but upon trying to view the dashboard I'm greeted by only 0.

I have tried disabling all plugins and changing themes, as well as resetting the roles in the db and creating another user.

Any next troubleshooting steps or tips on how the user id is determined / what could be causing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Side note issue occurred sometime after or from a server migration (table prefixes were not changed)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a form software bbpress interfering in some way with the queries for user permissions. If you find yourself in a similar situation there are a ton of resources on google, some of which may help and some that won't.

Try uninstalling your plugins (ne-name your plugins folder)
Try re-installing wordpress.
Attempt adding the function in the question to your page, and see if the correct user's permissions are being requested.